# Upload File as multipart/form-data from Angular with ngx-mat-file-input

Tags: angular, file-upload, multipart

I'm using `ngx-mat-file-input` [0] to retrieve a file input from the user and I want to upload it to a server. The endpoint expects a multipart-file. How can I do this?

[0] https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-material-file-input

Comment: Even though this seems kind of easy in the end I still struggeled some time with this. Hopefully I can help others with the same problem, so I posted this Q&A-style post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using `<ngx-mat-file-input>` with a reactive form it will give you back an object with a 'files' array. The elements of this array have the type 'File'. A File extends the Blob interface [0][1]. The Blob is what you need to send to the server.

**First step:** You have to wrap the result of the form inside a `FormData`-Object [2].

```
<!-- Minimal form -->
<form *ngIf="fileForm" [formGroup]="fileForm">
    <ngx-mat-file-input formControlName="file"></ngx-mat-file-input>
</form>
```

---

```
// the handler, e.g. if user presses "upload"-button
const file_form: FileInput = this.fileForm.get('file').value;
const file = file_form.files[0]; // in case user didn't selected multiple files

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file); // attach blob to formdata / preparing the request
```

*Notice*: You might expect that `.append` will return a new object like `HttpHeaders#append` but that is not the case here. `FormData#append` returns `void`. Therefore you can't do `const formData = new FormData().append('file', file);`!

**Second step:** Now pass the `FormData`-Object to `HttpClient#post`.

```
this.http.post<void>('/upload', formData).subscribe(() => {
  // worked
}, err => {
  console.error(err);
});
```

*Notice*: The server expects the file in the request parameter called 'file' because we set that name in the `FormData`-Object.

That's it.

---

A controller that accepts this file might look like shown down below(in this example: Java/Spring). Generally, it works with every controller, that accepts form multipart requests.

```
@PostMapping("/upload")
public void upload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {}
```

---

[0] https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/File

[1] Typescript Type Information (by your IDE)

[2] https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/FormData